# Check Menu Item is Enable With API Win32 in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, menu, delphi-xe

My problem in this code when Menu Item is Disable and then pass code "PostMessage" in Control Application to Crash because i need check menu Item is Enabled and then use PostMessage.

```
  HandleMenu:= GetMenu(ParentAppHandle);
  HandleMenu:= GetSubMenu(HandleMenu, 6 {menu item no});
  item:= GetMenuItemID(HandleMenu , 12 {sub menu item no});

  PostMessage(ParentAppHandle, WM_COMMAND, MakeWParam(item, 0), 0);
```

Comment: [GetMenuItemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx).

Comment: If you send a `WM_COMMAND` message for a disabled menu item, the receiving app should just ignore the message. If the receiver is crashing instead, the receiver is not coded properly. That is not the sender's fault. Also, make sure you have the correct `HWND` for the menu owner. Some app frameworks create a dedicated `HWND` for menu dispatching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the WinAPI function [GetMenuState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms647982%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Example:

```
var
  State: UINT;
begin
  State:= GetMenuState(HandleMenu , 12, MF_BYPOSITION);
  if (State and (MF_DISABLED or  MF_GRAYED)) = 0 then
  begin
    // Menu Item is enabled
  end
  else
  begin
    // Menu Item is disabled
  end;
```

Comment: From [GetMenuState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647982.aspx): *"The **GetMenuState** function has been superseded by the [**GetMenuItemInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx)"*. One reason to use `GetMenuItemInfo` is, that you no longer have to write compatibility code, checking for both disabled and grayed. They are being reported as the same value when using `GetMenuItemInfo`.